# how can we set table footer values dynamically using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to dynamically populate a table footer from a JSON data source. Here is the struture of the table

```
<table  id="example_table">
<tfoot id="example_footer">
<tr id="example-footer" style="font-weight:bold">
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>                                           
<th></th>
</tr>
</tfoot>  
</table>
```

I m planning to use the append() in jQuery as in the below fashion

```
$('#example_footer').append( '<tr>...</tr>' );
```

can anyone tell me how to access the tfooter and assign value form a js variable as it's content

Comment: Do you mean that your footer dissapears? or you need to change column names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually depends upon how your JSON is structured. Assuming that it is received in the variable 'data' and it has say 5 elements, the javascript would be somewhat like:

```
var tr = '<tr>';
tr+= '<th>'+data.element1+'</th>';
tr+= '<th>'+data.element2+'</th>';
tr+= '<th>'+data.element3+'</th>';
tr+= '<th>'+data.element4+'</th>';
tr+= '<th>'+data.element5+'</th>';
tr+= '</tr>';
$('#example_footer').append(tr);
```

Comment: I have already extracted the JSON data ans stored in 5 variables..Need to assign these variables as the footer content ..As u said is it possible to assign like,   tr+= '<th>'+variable1+'</th>';

Comment: Yes, so I think its not far-fetched now. You can simply use the variables and create the html for the row. Are you having any problems with that?

Comment: So  can I try like this 
'var tr = '<tr>';
tr+= '<th>'+variable1+'</th>';
tr+= '<th>'+variable2+'</th>';
tr+= '<th>'+variable3+'</th>';
tr+= '<th>'+variable4+'</th>';
tr+= '<th>'+variable5+'</th>';
tr+= '</tr>';
$('#example_footer').append(tr);'

Comment: I would suggest you to try out stuff before you ask questions, this will help you learn things yourself. Anyways, if you do find my answer helpful, then you can accept it.